# List all client certificates installed on user profiles in a domain

Tags: windows, certificate, client-certificate

I'm taking initial steps to start securing a network, and I've come across the fact that a number of machines have Client Certificates for websites installed in the user client certificate store, locally, rather than through AD. These are from a third-party CA, and are business critical.

As a first step, I'm trying to create a list of which certificates each user has installed, so that I can then try to create something more manageable using a GPO or similar, but as they were installed locally, I can't see them in my AD or Certificate Services.

I've been looking at powershell's certificate management cmdlets, but even then, I can only list the current user's certificates, which makes remoting with a domain administrator credential not a valid solution.

How do I go about cataloguing everybody's certificates?

Answer (score 2):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508243/retrieving-certificates-installed-under-a-different-user-get-childitem-cert-u) indicates that you cannot access the certificate store of another user.

One way i would think of is to write a logon script that will get the certificates of the current user at logon, for example with `Get-Childitem cert:\currentUser -recurse` and save the output to a local or network file. If you use `Export-CSV` you would get a format that you can easily process.

A possible one-Liner could be:

```
Get-Childitem Cert:\currentUser -Recurse |´
Select @{N="Username";E={$env:username}}, Subject, Issuer, FriendlyName, NotAfter |`
Export-CSV [csvFilePath] -Append
```

With the additional calculated property you get the username of the logged on user, so you can put the data in one file and still distinguish the certificates by user.